# Problema Intellij Idea muy raro, no puedo trabajar!

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

tengo un problema con intellij idea 2019.1.3 en el cual inicio y no me deja hacer click dentro de la aplicacion, como si el click del raton no funcionase, he desistalado y he vuelto a instalar y sigue el mismo error, pero si inicio desde la carpeta del programa, en el icono idea64.exe no hace nada directamente pero en idea.exe que supongo que sera el de 32 bits me da este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes me salia este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mirando por internet he creado un archivo que se llama idea.exe.vmoptions con el bloc de notas con el siguiente contenido

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1
```

y entoces ese error me desaparece y me aparece el primero que he puesto.

He desistalado el java y vuelto a instalarlo y sigue sin funcionarme, alguien me puede ayudar llevo toda la mañana perdida y no se que hacer, y no se ha tocado nada

He reinstalado tanto java como intellij y llego hasta la siguiente ventana, pero dentro de la ventana no hace click el raton, y si lo hago con el teclado aunque seleccione la version de evaluacion no puedo pasar al siguiente paso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como pone en el primer error, tienes declarada la Variable de entorno de `JAVA_HOME`? Click derecho en `equipo` -> propiedades -> Configuración avanzada del sistema -> Variables de entorno. Aqui tienes que tener una que se llame JAVA_HOME que indique la ruta del jdk.

Comment: Buenas, en primer lugar muchas gracias por contestar @x3k_js si la tengo declarada ahora updateo la pregunta y pongo mi path si es necesario por si lo tuviese mal

Comment: Updatea la informacion diciendo que ya tienes la variable de entorno puesta.  Supongo que has probado a reiniciar el ordenador después de la instalación de java etc...., Aun así ¿es posible que se te hayan terminado los días de las versión trial?

Comment: @x3k_js no si la instalacion es nueva eso no puede ser

Comment: @x3k_js voy a hacer una copia de seguridad y aprovecho para formatear el pc que tambien le hace falta

Comment: Agrega a tu pregnta el resultado de `where javac ` y `where java` si estas en windows que creo que es el caso